# Как произнести аксиому?

Tags: орфоэпия

Пусть предложение "X -> Y" произносится по-русски "Если Икс, то Игрек.".

Как произнести по-русски предложение "(X -> (Y -> Z)) -> ((X -> Y) -> (X -> Z))"?

Answer (score 2):

Месье знает толк в извращениях... Я бы сказал, что никак. Главное -- зачем?

Comment: Прочитано про "извращения".

Answer (score 1):

Именно для этого и используется "иероглифическая" письменность в математике. Перевести её на человеческий язык можно, например, так:

- Если из X следует, что из Y следует Z, то если из X следует Y, из X следует и Z.

Но это перевод на письменный вариант языка. В устном можно просто комбинировать *следует/если* в любом порядке, удачно расставив паузы и выделив цельные математические утверждения интонацией.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Без пауз и интонаций, обсуждаемое предложением можно произнести так: "Если Икс влечёт импликацию Игрек в Зет, то импликация Икс в Игрек влечёт импликацию Икс в Зет".

Comment: Да, хорошо. Математической логикой отдельно я не занимался, так что правильность терминологии — на вашей совести, но звучит понятно.